# How can I add a tag to a tag set?

Tags: tags

Using CiviCRM 4.7.16. I create a new tag and I want to add it to a tag set. But when I click on the Parent Tag pull down menu, it only shows tags that have not been assigned to a set. Tag sets are not shown. This is the case when both creating a new tag and editing a tag. I can't see another way to add a tag to a tag set.
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be right that this is a bug in 4.7.16. Fortunately it has been solved in 4.7.17.

This release includes a redesigned tag management screen with numerous improvements.

[image]

Update: 4.7.17 has been released.

Comment: Coleman, you mean 4.7 right, not 4.6? Thanks for confirming my suspicions. I'll look forward to the release of 4.7.17.

Comment: This was, indeed, resolved in 4.7.17 with the new tags management interface. Thanks again Coleman.